# How to use libxml2 with python on macOs?

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion, libxml2

I'm on OSX Lion and I have libxml2 installed (by default) and I have python installed (by default) but they don't talk to one another.  What's the simplest way to make this work on Lion?

```
$ python -c "import libxml2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named libxml2
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Visit ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/python/ and ensure [this is the latest version](ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/python/libxml2-python-2.6.21.tar.gz)
2. Download it
3. unpack it
4. open a term and cd to that directory
5. type `sudo python setup.py install`
6. `ls /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` and you should see a bunch of libxml2 files
7. try the test again and it should work

You'll need XCode installed, but like, you should already have that installed, right?

Comment: I haven't found MacPorts to be horrible in any fashion, and it's a great source of other python modules, too.  I can't speak for tkone's experience, but I highly recommend getting familiar with MacPorts if you find yourself working frequently with Python and other open source tools.

Comment: There's no reason to download and compile all of python just to get libxml2.  At least homebrew does a much saner job of not screwing up anything you've already installed to a directory it wants to use.

Comment: ...whereas I have found homebrew to have a much smaller package selection and a less useful package management system.  As I said, I'm personally happy with MacPorts, your mileage may vary, try out the alternatives and use what meets your needs.  Cheers!

Comment: I'm not advocating homebrew either. I'd just rather use virtualenv, pip and the occasional `python setup.py install`, which, thanks to virtualenv is local only to my virtualenv. no messing with anything on the system please.

Comment: For package in pypi, you don't even need to manually download, unzip and run `python setup.py install`. Just `pip install` in virtualenv and you're done.

Comment: I had tried pip but just pip install libxml didn't work and I was too lazy to search for it :)

Comment: failed to find headers for libxml2: update includes_dir

Answer (score 7):

tkone's answer is OK. But brew also can do it.

Try this,

```
  $ brew install libxml2 --with-python
```

Comment: Error: invalid option: --with-python

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the stock Python ships with the `libxml2` module.  You can install [macports](http://macports.org/), and then do this:

```
$ sudo port install py27-libxml2
```

...and after a short wait while everything installs, end up with Python 2.7, libxml2, and the libxml2 Python module.

Answer (score -4):

Just use [Pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to install python module packages, by typing :

```
sudo pip search libxml  and sudo pip install libxml
```

Comment: I don't think you tested this before you posted. Doesn't work. The package is lxml, but even that doesn't install very cleanly in my experience.