# Python: setup.py missing: No such file or directory

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I tried to update the libxml2 & libxslt packages as mine are too old to run with lxml. I found a walkthrough [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9797504/1794223) and tried to update the package with the command

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

but what I got was this error message:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS
/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

So apparently there is no setup.py file in my Python folder (this is my current Python version, I already checked this!). How is this possible? Hope someone can help me!

Comment: What directory are you running `setup.py` from? It is not supposed to be part of your actual python location. It comes with the packages.

Comment: Okay, now I see....! I thought setup.py belongs to the Python distribution...Thank you very much!

Comment: If @jdi has answered your question, a nice thing to do would be to set the question as answered :)

Answer (score 13):

To make this a formal answer from my comment...

setup.py is not part of the python installation location. It is included with the package that you wish to install. Change directories to the location of the source that you downloaded and then run the setup.py file.

Comment: I am not sure where downloaded file.How do we find that out?

Comment: @RamapriyaSridharan - You don't know where you download files to on your computer?

Comment: One way you can potentially find the setup.py if you don't remember is running a simple find command: "find . -name setup.py"