# Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Directory Change does not remove error

Tags: python, file, directory, cmd

I am trying to install pymysql to a windows 8 machine and have been having trouble with the installation for python 3.3 I got the mython-mysql driver to work fine for 2.7 but this is giving me some issues
so far I have been denied access which I fixed with

`runas /savecred /user:Luke "python setup.py install"`
luke is an administrator profile and should have access but this prompts on a second window the following error:

`Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.`

to fix this I prefaced the install command with:

```
cd C:\Python33\PyMySQL\py3k\
```

unfortunately this did not fix the problem and still receiving the same error message.

i have checked [Python: setup.py missing: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443472/python-setup-py-missing-no-such-file-or-directory) but it only said to change the directory which I have tried

Does anyone have any idea as to why this might be happening? The file is there. why can't it read or find it?

Comment: I installed the py3k build (build-py3k.sh) with cygwin but there was a patch file. could the patch file be the key? it's name was setup.py.py3k.patch

Comment: Check where Python is installed using the "where" command (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304319/is-there-an-equivalent-of-which-on-the-windows-command-line). I have only used the Unix which equivalent, so YMMV.

Comment: I used the where command and it gave me "C:\Python33\PyMySQL\py3k\setup.py" so I ran:
runas /savecred /user:Luke "python C:\Python33\PyMySQL\py3k\setup.py install"
and it returned the same error

Comment: Try python --version and tell me which version of python it returns

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps in order to rectify this problem:

1. Download tweepy and unzip it in Desktop: [Download from this
   link](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy)
2. Rename it tweepy
3. Open command prompt and type "cd
   desktop" then "cd tweepy"
4. Type "python setup.py install"

Comment: Didn't work for me. I got..... The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the installation directory:  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-29327.write-test'

Comment: Belay that! I'm still a complete noob with Linux, but I made a wild guess and retried step 4 as "**sudo** python setup.py install"   - BINGO!